# @HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ]) event not firing for all tabs in angular while closing browser

Tags: angular

When angular application is opened in multiple tabs when we close browser
 @HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ]) event not firing for all tabs it is firing for active tab only.

Comment: ... and the question is? This seems more like a bug report. (And a poorly made one at that)

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting the browser to do? Each tab is a new instance of the client app on its own. For instance, if you open an incognito window/tab or open the app in another browser, the behavior won't depend on events from other windows/tabs/browsers.

It seems that what you want to achieve needs a different approach, such as `WebSockets`. Have a look at the [socket.io docs](https://socket.io/).